# no such element exception after using a proxy wrapper

Tags: selenium, page-factory, invocationhandler

In order to close a random pop up on my web page, I followed a tutorial of wrapping web elements with a proxy wrapper:
https://www.vinsguru.com/selenium-webdriver-how-to-handle-annoying-random-popup-alerts/

After implementing this solution in my code, the random pop up got closed but I encountered 'no such element exception' which I didn't have previously. I tried to change the line of the code by using different elements and methods but non of my actions resolved this problem - non of the elements were recognized .

I will appreciate any help :)

The method which causing the exception (the last line):

```
private void search(String gameName) {
    Wait.visible(homeBtn);
    Methods.click(searchBtn);
    Methods.sendKeys(searchBox, gameName);  
    Wait.visible(searchResultsTitle);    
}
```

proxy page factory class:

```
public class ProxyPageFactory {

 public static <T> void initElements(WebDriver driver, T pageobject){
        
     //first init elements
     PageFactory.initElements(driver, pageobject);
        
     //then access all the WebElements and create a wrapper
     for(Field f: pageobject.getClass().getDeclaredFields()){
         if(f.getType().equals(WebElement.class)){
             boolean accessible = f.isAccessible();
             f.setAccessible(true);
         
             //reset the webelement with proxy object
             try {
                 f.set(pageobject, ElementGuard.guard((WebElement)f.get(pageobject))); 
             } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {         
                 e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }          
         
        f.setAccessible(accessible);
     }  
  }
}
```

element guard class:

```
public class ElementGuard {

public static WebElement guard(WebElement element) {
    ElementProxy proxy = new ElementProxy(element);
    WebElement wrappdElement = (WebElement) Proxy.newProxyInstance(ElementProxy.class.getClassLoader(),
                                                                   new Class[] { WebElement.class },
                                                                   proxy);
    return wrappdElement;
}
```

element proxy class:

```
public class ElementProxy implements InvocationHandler {

   private final WebElement element;

   public ElementProxy(WebElement element) {
       this.element = element;
   }

   @Override
   public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
      //before invoking actual method check for the popup
      this.checkForPopupAndKill();
      return  (method.invoke(element, args));
   }

   private void checkForPopupAndKill() {    
     // closing the pop up
   } }
```

the error:

> java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.isDisplayed(Unknown Source)
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementIfVisible(ExpectedConditions.java:314)
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:43)
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:300)
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:297)
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.lambda$checkConditionInLoop$2(FluentWait.java:233)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1764)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1756)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1016)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1665)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1598)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
> at ✽.I perform an action to invoke the block(file:///C:/Users/may/Desktop/automation-git/GTH-QA/cucumber/features/Blocks.feature:9)
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
> at infrastructure.ElementProxy.invoke(ElementProxy.java:27)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.isDisplayed(Unknown Source)
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementIfVisible(ExpectedConditions.java:314)
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:43)
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:300)
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:297)
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.lambda$checkConditionInLoop$2(FluentWait.java:233)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1764)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1756)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1016)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1665)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1598)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(text(),'SEARCH RESULTS')]"}
> (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)
> For documentation on this error, please visit: https://selenium.dev/exceptions/#no_such_element
> *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//div[contains(text(),'SEARCH RESULTS')]}
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor15.newInstance(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:196)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:129)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:160)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:582)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:333)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:451)
> at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:394)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:325)
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:70)
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:39)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.isDisplayed(Unknown Source)
> ... 17 more

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for including the relevant code. It's not entirely clear what is working and what is failing after dealing with the popup, but it sounds like there may be an issue with defining all the page model elements at one time. (Which is why it is a good idea to only instantiate elements as you need them, because if the page is dynamic the references can go stale.)

One thing that would be helpful to know is if this element was ever found successfully before?

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(text(),'SEARCH RESULTS')]"}
```

If it was, your xpath is fine but the WebElement reference has lost relevance. Try re-creating that WebElement from scratch *after* the popup, and see if that solves the problem. You may need to refresh the page model data each time you deal with the popup window.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) the line `Wait.visible(searchResultsTitle);`  doesn't work. It worked before I used the ProxyPageFactory to initialize my webElements but now any line of code that I write in the end of the search method doesn't work. I tried your solution to recreate the element but that didn't work too

Comment: In that case you will need to do some investigation with an xpath viewer. Manually go through the steps of your code until you have closed the popup, and then try to see if the xpath viewer can find searchResultsTitle. If it can, then there is something about the Selenium focus or the freshness of the webelement. If it can't, use developer tools to see if the element changed its identifiers somehow after the popup is gone (rare, but it does happen)